# Subview in Main View crash When assigning Image from AVFoundation to UIImageView

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, nsthread

I have created a custom **AVFoundation** camera and loaded into another view as subview with **@IBDesignable**, after the image is taken I would like to assign it to `UIImageView`, But when the button is pressed, the custom camera view (`UIView`) crash and move up in the screen, instead of assigning it to the `UIImageView`, This happens when the custom camera view load at the beginning, then when I load the custom camera view again, it will assign the image to the `UIImageView`.

**Capture Image method:**

```
@IBAction func captureImage(sender: AnyObject) {
        if let stillOutput = self.captureImageOutput {
            // we do this on another thread so that we don't hang the UI
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)) {
                //find the video connection
                var videoConnection : AVCaptureConnection?
                for connecton in stillOutput.connections {
                    //find a matching input port
                    for port in connecton.inputPorts!{
                        if port.mediaType == AVMediaTypeVideo {
                            videoConnection = connecton as? AVCaptureConnection
                            break //for port
                        }
                    }

                    if videoConnection  != nil {
                        break// for connections
                    }
                }
                if videoConnection  != nil {
                    stillOutput.captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection(videoConnection){
                        (imageSampleBuffer : CMSampleBuffer!, _) in

                        let imageData = AVCaptureStillImageOutput.jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation(imageSampleBuffer)
                        let pickedImage: UIImage = UIImage(data: imageData, scale: 1.0)!

                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                            self.capturePhoto.image = pickedImage
                        })
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

I have also tried the **`dispatch_sync`** and nothing load in the **UIImageView**,but the screen don't crash.

```
dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
      self.capturePhoto.image = pickedImage
})
```

Comment: what kind of crash are you getting?  is there a backtrace that shows what line of your source code is causing the crash?

Comment: I don't get any error. @MichaelDautermann

Comment: Have you tried to place `NSLog()` calls inside your function at major steps so you could localise the place where you crash?

Comment: @JohnTracid How do you do that?

Answer (score -1):

I just tested it and this worked for me (Swift 2.0)

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    imageView = UIImageView(frame: self.view.frame)
    self.view.addSubview(imageView)
}

func takeImage() {

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)) {

        guard let videoConnection = self.stillImageOutput.connectionWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo) else { return }
        guard videoConnection.enabled else { return }

        self.stillImageOutput.captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection(videoConnection) { (buffer: CMSampleBuffer!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

            let imageData = AVCaptureStillImageOutput.jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation(buffer)
            let image: UIImage = UIImage(data: imageData, scale: 1.0)!

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                self.imageView.image = image
                print("picture taken")
            })
        }
    }

}
```

The image is successfully taken and added to the ViewController. If this doesn't work for you, maybe you can explain more on your setup so I can try and reproduce the error/crash.